# Avoiding getting "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost'" message with Django + Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a Django app setup on Elastic Beanstalk. Working and running great.

I have my settings file set up with only the allowed hosts needed --

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com']`

I get the Django errors sent to my email -- which normally I like. However, every time I redeploy my app (which I do from uploading a ZIP folder, not through CLI) I get this message

`Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost'. You may need to add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

I'm having no problems running my site, I just don't like getting this error. I think I could just add localhost (or 127.0.0.1 probably) as an allowed host--however I'm not sure if this is a good idea for security reasons.

What might be happening here and how can I fix it? Is adding these hosts OK?

EDIT:

To clarify, this is happening when I *deploy* my code to Elastic Beanstalk -- not when I'm running it locally.

Comment: You can create two settings file. One for production and one for development. In development file you can add `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in the ALLOWED_HOST, and in [production settings you add `mysite.com`. So whenever you run your application in production,, you need to call production_settings.py and in developement you can work with dev_settings.py. Is this you are looking for?

Comment: @ReemaParakh No -- I already have that setup with something like `if PRODUCTION_STATUS == 'LOCAL' then ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]`

Comment: In that case, to run locally you need `localhost`  or `127.0.0.1` in settings file.

Answer (score -1):

You have provided your domain in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but when you're running the project locally it still needs the request to come from your `mysite.com`. So you need add `localhost` also to you `ALLOWED_HOSTS`:

`Settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
                'mysite.com',
                'localhost:8000',                 #<-- add this
                '127.0.0.1:8000'                  #<-- add these just in case
                ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I'm not talking about running the project locally though.

Comment: @bones225, did you resolve this problem?  I currently have the same issue.

Comment: @NeilAggarwal I did not. I'm guessing putting ```localhost``` in product ```ALLOWED_HOSTS``` would fix this, however I don't know enough about the security implications of this to feel comfortable doing this. I figure one error email every time I deploy... I got other fish to fry xD